# Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Server could not parse the Url

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the 1.4.1 version of DocumentDB client for .Net and when I try to update a document in the collection I get this error:

> DocumentClientException: Server could not parse the Url.

When I do:

```
await _repository.Client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(DocumentsLink, document);
```

where Client is a DocumentClient and DocumentsLink is an URI for path *dbs/9TBhAA==/colls/9TBhANQ4yAA=/docs/*

constructed this way:

```
public Uri DocumentsLink
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_documentsLink))
        {
            _documentsLink = _repository.Collection.DocumentsLink;
        }
        return new Uri(_documentsLink, UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

and document a simple json doc.

This code has been working fine on a different collection on the same database.

I get the same error if I use the linq extension and pass a string instead of a relative URI.

Anyone has pointers on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the uri really `adbs/9TBhAA==/colls/9TBhAPqqYgE=/docs/`? It shouldn't start with `a`.

Comment: Indeed it's a typo in the question, I'm adjusting the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's odd; are you sure this worked on a different collection in the same database?

`ReplaceDocumentAsync()` requires a full path to a specific document. The path, `dbs/9TBhAA==/colls/9TBhANQ4yAA=/docs/`, only resolves to a collection.

You need to append the rid of the document - which will look something like this: `dbs/UtJlAA==/colls/UtJlAKU5IAE=/docs/UtJlAKU5IAELAAAAAAAAAA==/`

Comment: You are right. Although the link parameter in the methods Create and Replace have the same name (documentCollectionUri) the method summary is different. I'm still baffled as to why this didn't occur on the other collection but it's not the reason of this post. Thanks!